# avoid duplicate file upload

Tags: servlets, upload, duplicates

I want to design an application which uploads .xlsx files without duplication. The condition for duplication is as follows:
   If user attempts to upload file with same data and same name as previously available on server then the file should not be uploaded.
   But if he uploads file with different data and same name as previously available on server then the file should be uploaded on server.

The jsp i have written is as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<script> 
var _validFileExtensions = [".xlsx"];    
function Validate(oForm) {
    var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oInput.type == "file") {
            var sFileName = oInput.value;
            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                var blnValid = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                        blnValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!blnValid) {
                    alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
<center>
<h3> File Upload</h3>
<br>
<form action="./UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
Select .xlxs to upload <br>
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" size="50">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My servlet is as follows:

```
package com.ideas.webapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@WebServlet(name = "servlet", urlPatterns = { "/UploadServlet" })

public class uploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "upload";



    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // checks if the request actually contains upload file
        if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {
            PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
            writer.println("Request does not contain upload data");
            writer.flush();
            return;
        }

        // configures upload settings
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);


        // constructs the directory path to store upload file
        String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("")
            + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
        // creates the directory if it does not exist
        File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
            uploadDir.mkdir();
        }

        try {
            // parses the request's content to extract file data
            List formItems = upload.parseRequest(req);
            Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

            // iterates over form's fields
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                // processes only fields that are not form fields
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                    File storeFile = new File(filePath);

                    // saves the file on disk
                    item.write(storeFile);
                }
            }
           System.out.println("Upload has been done successfully!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("There was an error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/uploadFile.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }       
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean data as in file content or as in date it has been changed? Could this be a property of the file you could check? If the last modified date is after the one stored, allow it to upload?

Comment: last modified date could be one of the approach.. Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way would be to keep a list of checksums (MD5, SHA1, ... choose one) of previously uploaded files, and check, whether the checksum of the currently uploaded file is in the list.

To save the bandwith, you could also perform the check browser-side (using AJAX to get the list of checksums), **but** you have to do it also server-side, as there is always the possibility for the user to avoid the browser-side check and upload the file directly. In such case, you need to detect and refuse it.